# Is a curve's curvature invariant under rotation and uniform scaling?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

The title really say's it all, but once again is a curve's curvature invariant under rotation and uniform scaling?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A curve's curvature is invariant under rotation. Intuitively, a curve turns just as much no matter how it is oriented. More formally, for a curve $\gamma(s)$ that is parametrized by arc length, the curvature is $\kappa(s) = ||\gamma''(s)||$. Rotation does not change the length of the $\gamma''(s)$ vector, only the direction; therefore, rotation does not affect curvature.

A curve's curvature is not invariant under uniform scaling, however. Consider the example of a circle. All circles are the same up to scaling, but they don't all have the same curvature; in general, a circle of radius r has curvature 1/r.

Comment: D'oh, I forget about think of curvature as the radius.